# Can't create a vaadin application since the archetype entry is missing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, vaadin

Despite having already created maven projects with the Vaadin archetype, the entry is missing this time. I create a new maven project an when I search for vaadin in the archetype selection, the list is empty.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this. http://www.whycouch.com/2012/05/how-to-create-vaadin-project-in-eclipse.html

Comment: @abaghel That's it thanks :)